# Why can't I add things directly to UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I'm new to iOS programming and maybe I don't fully understand the `UIScrollView`. From what I've researched, all methods of making a scroll view include embed a `UIView` or `UIImageView` into a `UIScrollView`. However, I don't know whether there is a way to directly drag objects (`UILabel`, `UIButton`...) to `UIScrollView`. And if the size of `UIScrollView` is set to be larger than the screen, then everything on the `UIScrollView` is scrollable. Again, that's all my thoughts and I don't find any post to confirm or deny this. I think if it's possible, then it's the easiest way to set up a scrollable screen.

If that's not possible, can anyone point to an easy way to scroll a long list of `UIButton`s (only vertically)? I found many tutorials but most are for scrolling a `UIImageView` and I can't adopt the method to a `UIView` containing the list of `UIButton`s. Thanks very much for helping me.

I'm in iOS 5 and storyboard mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Scrollview` is great for `documents`, `images`, `webviews`, etc...

But for laying out UI it's a bit of a pain.

If you're just laying out `buttons` vertically then you might want to look at using `UITableView` to manage the layout for you.

`UITableView` is good for more than just displaying lists of data.

If you want to stick with `scrollView` then you can create a new `UIView` nib file and make that the full size you want it to be. Drag all your buttons into it and then put THIS `UIView` into your `scrollView` using code.

That way you've done the layout with IB dragging the buttons but still use the code to put all of those `buttons` etc into the `scrollview`.

Comment: The reason why I don't want to use `UITableView` is that I can't directly add action (touch) to a cell and the solutions I searched are more complicated than what I should do if I just want to scroll a list of buttons in a `UIVIew`.

Comment: Then use the second alternative I suggested.

Comment: @zyl1024 Adding a touch to a cell is actually trivial. Just block cell selection and add a tap recognizer to the table.

Answer (score 2):

Because `UIImageView`, `UILabel`, `UIButton` is a descendants of `UIView` you can add instances of those classes usin `addSubview:` method.

Also you need to properly setup frames of your views.

If you want scrollable content size larger than screen size so you need to set scrollView.contentSize to needed value.

Answer (score 1):

Of cause. Case `UILabel`, `UIButton` ... is `subClass` of `UIView`. You can add `UIView` to `ScrollView` ,you could add them,too.so do `UIScrollView`,for it comes from `UIView`,too.

Use `View` to contain the `button` let you manage the buttons easily.

you should calculate all the frames of the buttons.if they have some same layout feature, you would like to use `tableView`.

Comment: The reason why I don't want to use `UITableView` is that I can't directly add action (touch) to a cell and the solutions I searched are more complicated than what I should do if I just want to scroll a list of buttons in a `UIVIew`.

Comment: I see. well, you could find some article about the realization of tableView's principle.
It uses Flyweight Pattern,less memory cast.
You can do the same thing in your scrollView,or if you add lots of button to it,memory warn easy to show.

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard I suggest not adding UILabel etc. directly to the scroll view. It can be done but I found it easier having only one view (or very fiew) directly in the containing view of a scroll view. Especially when a single view is larger than the screen.

That's why I suggest to crate one plain UIView object. Use freestyle size for drawing the UIView in IB. That should be your only direct subview to the scroll view. Within that view you can easily arrange and rearrange all your ui items. But make sure that you do not use autolayout and that your view does not resize the subvies and the scroll view does not autoresize the subviews. Otherwise your properly layouted view, that is supposed to be larger than the screen, could be quiezed into the screens (respectively available parts of the window) dimensions.